# Send multiple POST requests a once

Tags: php, python, ios, server, backend

I have an iOS app that is send a POST request to my server and then it runs a function and returns some data back to the app.

My question is if my app has lets say 100 people using it at the same time and make the POST request in quick succession, is this going to case an error?

I am on a shared server if that matters.

Comment: no it will not cause any error for testing you can you use like jmeter to send x post requests and check, it will slow down your app depends on server

Comment: We can't know. It depends on the server and what it does, and the server provider (who you should talk to)

Comment: Completely agree with Wain, Its completely depends on Server strength to handle Request whether request sent from Different device or from the same device, until Server have any Restriction based on same IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Use AFNetworking for making POST request to server in iOS.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager =    [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.requestSerializer.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];
    //manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

    [manager POST:'webservice url' parameters:'webservice parameters 'timeoutInterval:120 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

}
```

if 100 people are making same call at a time I think it doesn't cause an error.As 100 people will make call through different device so different device ID.

Comment: I dnt think Device ID matters even. Its completely depends on Server strength to handle Request whether request sent from Different device or from the same device, until Server have any Restriction based on same IP address.

Answer (score 0):

No it should not cause an error, you are requesting the server with an `HTTP` method(`POST`) which serves every request from a new user as a new request because HTTP is a stateless protocol it doesn't save user states(unless you are managing user sessions explicitly)

So if 100 users are requesting at the same time, they are different, each request is different and same will be the response(different) for each user.

And as others said, its completely dependent on the server how it handles the request.